# Как правильно вставить html в php

Tags: php, html

Как правильно добавить html теги labe label- к коду:

```php
    $result[$key]['status']=

    "<span class="label label-.get_status_color($value['status']).">".

    $data['TransactionStatus'][$value['status']].

    '</span>'
```

Текущий вариант не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result[$key]['status']=

'<span class="label label-'.get_status_color($value['status']).'">'.

$data['TransactionStatus'][$value['status']].

'</span>'
```